# Java Swing MVC one common VIEW for all separate JPanels(views)

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to write an application in Java swing, based od MVC pattern.

The application has two functionalities ('TfwCreator' and 'FlightCalculator').

Each functionality has got its own model, view and controller.
Each view of functionality is represented as class extending JPanel.

Main class called 'PhotoMate' has also it's own view represented as JFrame('PhotoMateView') which is going to be the common view for the subviews('TfwView' and 'CalculatorView').

To add each subview(JPanel) I'm using constructor of common view.

It seems to be wrong assuming there will be more JPanels.

The question is - what's the best way of adding those panels to JFrame(common view)?
And the second question - should I create separate controller for the common view?

Here is the code:

PhotoMateView class (common view):

```
public class PhotoMateView extends JFrame {

    private JTabbedPane bookmarks = new JTabbedPane();

    public PhotoMateView(JPanel panel1, JPanel panel2){

        this.setTitle("PhotoMate v.1");

        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout());

        this.add(bookmarks);

        bookmarks.add("TFW", panel1);

        bookmarks.add("Calc", panel2);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Main method:

```
package photo_mate;

import tfw_creator.TfwController;
import tfw_creator.TfwModel;
import tfw_creator.TfwView;
import flight_calculator.CalculatorController;
import flight_calculator.CalculatorModel;
import flight_calculator.CalculatorView;

public class PhotoMate {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    TfwModel tfwModel = new TfwModel();
    TfwView tfwView = new TfwView();
    TfwController tfwController = new TfwController(tfwView, tfwModel);

    CalculatorModel calcModel = new CalculatorModel();
    CalculatorView calcView = new CalculatorView();
    CalculatorController calcController = new CalculatorController(calcView, calcModel);

    PhotoMateView photoMateView = new PhotoMateView(tfwView, calcView);
}
```

Comment: Sound like you should be using a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) which will allow you to swap panels in the frame.

Comment: Thanks for replay, but I wonder what's the right way of sending those panels to JFrame. Keeping them as instance variables? What would I do if there was 10 - 20 panels?

Comment: To switch beetwen panels I will use JTabbedPane.

Comment: If you don't have to, don't extend `JFrame`.